# Pass a class gotten from Reflection to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

this is a dummy example what I am trying to do:

```
var ass = Assembly.Load("Dummy.Class.FullName");

var yy =
    from t in ass.GetTypes()
    let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyTestAttribute), true)
    where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
    select new { Type = t, Attributes = attributes.Cast<MyTestAttribute>() };

foreach (var x in yy)
{
    TestOpen<typeof(x.Type)>();
}

private void TestOpen<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
}
```

I can´t get a class definition and pass to a generic method this way, I tried everything, I guess I am missing something in special that the method is waiting some compiled class and from reflection I can´t get this, correct?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to generate the proper method definition, and call it via reflection.

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();

var mi = thisType.GetMethod("TestOpen");

foreach (var x in yy)
{
    var gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(x.Type);
    gmi.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Reed ! On this my Dummy example this works, but  I am trying to put inside a Relaycommand... it´s not working so well.

var rcom  = new RelayCommand(this.TestOpen<gmi.Invoke(this, null)>, () => true)

private void TestOpen<TEntity>() where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
}

Comment: @2Fast4YouBR Difficult to know for sure, but you probably want:  `var rcom = new RelayCommand(() => gmi.Invoke(this, null), () => true);`

Comment: Thanks @Reed , sorry for my mistake, after few hours looking into this, cuold see that the gmi was doing the work for me! cheers